# vhdl-ultrasonic sensor(hc-sr04)

Tags: vhdl, sensors, fpga

I have a project. In my project, I am creating a car that keeps the distance between anything next to the car and the car itself. But, coding is a headache for me. I created 3 different project, and all of them seemed to me okay. Yet none of them worked in practice. Then, I created this code(the most basic one to understand-- no component at all).

The sensor need 10 us pulse and waits for new pulse for 100ms. When I send the trigger signal, sensor responses and sends a ultrasonic wave. While it waits to recieve the echo back, the sensor sends 5v signal and and I find the duration of this signal. According to thisduration, I change the signal(motor) to 10,01 or to 11. In theory, ıt works but in preactice it does not work.

here is the code.

```
begin
  process(clk)
    variable c1,c2: integer:=0;
    variable y :std_logic:='1';
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then

        if(c1=0) then
            trig<='1';
        elsif(c1=500) then--100us
            trig<='0';
            y:='1';
        elsif(c1=5000000) then-- 100 ms
            c1:=0;
            trig<='1';
        end if;
        c1:=c1+1;

        if(echo = '1') then
            c2:=c2+1;
        elsif(echo = '0' and y='1' ) then-- I change the y to not get echo_time =0;
            echo_time<= c2;
            c2:=0;
            y:='0';
        end if;

        if(echo_time < 100000) then--20 cm
            motor<="10";
        elsif(echo_time > 150000)then--30 cm
            motor<="01";
        else-- between  
            motor<="11";
        end if;
    end if; 
end process ;
```

`

I could not solve my problem. Everything seems fine to me. I created a simulation and imaginary signal. On pc, it works, but in the real life it doesn't.

Pleeaaassssee help me.

Edit: Problem solved, code is working. I was giving 3.3V to sensor as Vcc, then I realized that I should give 5v. It worked. Thank you for everyone.

Comment: Please tell us what doesn't seem to work, what error do you get or what output do you get.

Comment: there is no error in coding part. The error is logical I assume. Normally, when the sensor sees my hand, it should change the motor to 01 or 11. But I always see the motor as 10 like the distance is 0. First I assımed the sensor is burned , then I got a new one an the result is the same. The leds that represents the motor are always 10. This is the problem.

Comment: There's a relationship between the surface area of the target and sensing distance, at 40 KHz expect a hand to attenuate any reflection. Try something bigger. Verify your trigger to the HC-SR04 and you're getting something back.  Is your range gate arithmetic correct for the frequency of`clk`? See [XuLA/FPGA/XuLA_lib GitHub](https://github.com/xesscorp/XuLA/tree/master/FPGA/XuLA_lib) Common.vhd and Hcsr04.vhd uses Reals to determine counts for `clk_i` frequency, output those in naturals by Report statements (only need part of the package declarations in CommonPckg, comment out unisim context).

Comment: I looked at the codes you referred and I couldn't manage to create what you said. Can you help me more.

Comment: Did you run this code in simulation? If so, how does the testbench look? Can you record the response of the sensor with a scope or LA? What FPGA and tool chain do you have? Also consider using a proper reset of the counters.

Comment: It will only give at most one pulse on "trig".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, code is working. I was giving 3.3V to sensor as Vcc, then I realized that I should give 5v. It worked. Thank you for everyone.