# Can't run HC - SR04 Sensor (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, sensors, fpga

I'm a student working on a project, on a custom designed board that has a Spartan-6 FPGA on board. My project is to make a game that outputs its interface through HDMI, and recieves input via a sensor. My sensor is the HC - SR04 (http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf). All modules are wokring, except for the sensor module. I'm not getting any warning or errors.
The following shows my code for the module, in which I created a finite state machine to run through the stages required to send/receive data from the sensor.
Note that I have an additional state than what is required in the datasheet, but that shouldn't be a problem since it doesn't trigger the sensor.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Sensor is
    Port (  clk  :  in      STD_LOGIC; --24 MHz
                Echo     :  in      STD_LOGIC;
        Trig     :  out STD_LOGIC;
        Echo_Time:  out integer
    );
end Sensor;

architecture Behavioral of Sensor is

type state_type is (    Init_state, Trigger_state, Echo_state);


signal  state       :   state_type  := Init_state;
signal  echoing     :   std_logic   := '0';             -- determines if we are echoing or not
signal  echoReceived    :   std_logic   := '0';             -- determines if we are echoing or not
signal  d       :   integer;                                -- the first and highest possible delay, this is 20 ms
signal  en_timer    :   std_logic;                          --active high
signal  rst_timer   :   std_logic;                          --active high


signal cnt_timer    : integer := 0;--was 19,
signal final_timer  : integer := 0;--was 19,

begin

state_machine: process (clk, cnt_timer, echoReceived)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if state = Init_state then
                if cnt_timer = d then
                    state <= Trigger_state;
                    rst_timer <= '1';
                else
                    rst_timer <= '0';
                end if;
            elsif state = Trigger_state then
                if cnt_timer = d then
                    state <= Echo_state;
                    rst_timer <= '1';
                else
                    rst_timer <= '0';
                end if;
            elsif state = Echo_state then
                if echoReceived = '1' then--change this one
                    state <= Init_state;
                    rst_timer <= '1';
                else
                    rst_timer <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
      end if;
    end process;


timer: process(clk, en_timer,rst_timer)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if en_timer = '1' and rst_timer = '0' then
                cnt_timer <= cnt_timer + 1;
            elsif rst_timer = '1' then
                cnt_timer <= 0;
            end if;
        end if;             
    end process;


state_machine_output: process(state, Echo, echoing,cnt_timer)
    begin

            --internal signals
            en_timer        <= '0';

            --state machine signals
            d               <= 0;
            echoing         <= '0';
            echoReceived            <= '0';
            final_timer     <= 0;
            --external signals
            Trig            <= '0';
        if state = Init_state then

            en_timer        <= '1';
            Trig            <= '0';
            d           <= 48; -- this will delay the system by 2 us
            echoing         <= '0';
            echoReceived            <= '0';
        elsif state = Trigger_state then    

            en_timer        <= '1';
            Trig            <= '1';
            d           <= 240; -- this will delay the system by 10 us
            echoing         <= '0';
            echoReceived    <= '0';
        elsif state = Echo_state then   --think about it later

            if Echo = '1' then
                en_timer    <= '1';
                echoing     <= '1';
            elsif Echo = '0' and echoing = '1' then
                final_timer     <= cnt_timer;
                en_timer        <= '0';
                echoing     <= '0';
                echoReceived    <= '1'; 
            end if;

        else

            --internal signals
            en_timer        <= '0';

            --state machine signals
            d           <= 0;
            echoing         <= '0';
            echoReceived            <= '0';
            final_timer     <= 0;
            --external signals
            Trig            <= '0';

        end if;
    end process;

Echo_Time   <= final_timer;--output data here

end Behavioral;
```

So, my question is whether my logic here is correct or not, because I'm only getting 0 from Echo_time.

Also, note that the sensor is working fine with arduino.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there is no specific problem nor is there an indication of a correct result.  Your question is otherwise a duplicate of [vhdl-ultrasonic sensor(hc-sr04)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580741/vhdl-ultrasonic-sensorhc-sr04) which has an accepted answer and shows code. There's also the vhdl tag on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) for peer review.

Comment: I Have seen this post already. But, I'm trying to get my own code to work, as I will be graded on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo_time is always 0 because of these code lines:

```
if Echo = '1' then
  en_timer    <= '1';
  echoing     <= '1';
elsif Echo = '0' and echoing = '1' then
  final_timer     <= cnt_timer;
  en_timer        <= '0';
  echoing     <= '0';
  echoReceived    <= '1';
end if;
```

Trace the signal from the output:

1. `Echo_time` is equal to `final_timer`.
2. `final_timer` is always 0 except if `Echo = '0' and echoing = '1'`
3. echoing is always 0 except if `Echo = '1'`
4. because `Echo` is either 0 or 1, final timer can not be positive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you could improve with your design:

- Check your sensitivity lists: for a synchronous process it should contain the clock only (plus asynchronous sets and/or resets if any).
- Do not initialize your signals at declaration. This does not work with all synthesizers and/or hardware targets. Use an explicit reset, that is another input of your module, to initialize what must be.

Once you will have fixed this, you should simulate before synthesizing and running on the hardware: it is much easier to debug with simulations.